# the syntax of hashtable in sml

Tags: hashtable, smlnj

I am trying to create a hashtable in SML-NJ, where I can insert and retrieve values using a key, however, i getting a syntax error which I am not sure why.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
exception cannot_find_it

val mkTable : (('a -> word) * (('a * 'a) -> bool)) -> (int * exn)
  -> ('a,'b) hash_table

val t : (string,int) hash_table = mkTable (HashString.hashString, op =)(11, 
cannot_find_it)

insert t("mike",30);
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
map.sml:8.1-8.4 Error: syntax error: replacing  VAL with  ARROW
uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:42.54
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:299.20-299.23
```